# I tried simple print function using react-to-print. Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

Tags: reactjs

I tried to print simple table using react-to-print. I got

> Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," at line no 24 "const".

I am new to react.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import ReactToPrint, { PrintContextConsumer } from 'react-to-print';

import { ComponentToPrint } from './ComponentToPrint';

export default class Form extends Component {
    
render() {

        return (
          <table>
            <thead>
              <th>column 1</th>
              <th>column 2</th>
              <th>column 3</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>data 1</td>
                <td>data 2</td>
                <td>data 3</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        
        const Example = () => {
            const componentRef = useRef();
            const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
              content: () => componentRef.current,
            });
          
            return (
              <div>
                <ComponentToPrint ref={componentRef} />
                <button onClick={handlePrint}>Print this out!</button>
              </div>        );
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess it's about the comma at the end of line `content: () => componentRef.current,`. Remove it.

Comment: You can not write something like "const Example" in return of render. You can use only `jsx` in that place. 
And also brackets don't match in your code.

Comment: i removed that comma now but no changes. and what can i replace instead of that   "const example ". and i don't understand which bracket that mismatch i checked endpoints. i am noob to this so only this much of doubt. thanks in advance.

Comment: Firstly, your code is missing the closing bracket for the `return` call (which is right after `render()`). But fixing it doesn't help much, because you seem to be missing the basic idea of how it should be organized (s. my answer below).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for necro posting, but since the answer is missing, let's fix this!

---

Here your `Form` is what should be used in place of `ComponentToPrint`, and of course it must be separate from your `Example` functional component.

That's how it is!

To explain in more details, you should have two jsx (as an example):

```
form.jsx
--------

import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Form extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <table>
                <thead>
                  <th>column 1</th>
                  <th>column 2</th>
                  <th>column 3</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>data 1</td>
                    <td>data 2</td>
                    <td>data 3</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
        );
    }
}
```

-- this is your "component to print" (i.e. it returns what will be printed out).

And also you need

```
example.jsx
-----------

import Form from './form';

import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { useReactToPrint } from 'react-to-print';

const Example = () => {
    const componentRef = useRef();
    const handlePrint = useReactToPrint({
      content: () => componentRef.current,
    });
    
    return (
      <div>
        <Form ref={componentRef} />
        <button onClick={handlePrint}>Print this out!</button>
      </div>
    );
}
```

-- this is your component (functional component) with "Print this out!" button which takes ref to your `Form` as the content for printing.

All that's left is to use your `Example` somewhere in the App, it will produce the table and a button, clicking the button will call printer dialogue.